# Too many levels of symbolic links nvim

Tags: ubuntu, config, symlink, neovim

I have used my nvim config folder (~/.config/nvim) for a long time, and now suddenly i cant access it. I am not very familiar with symlinks and i have not created this link myself. I also find i wierd that the relative path **.nvim** is linked to its own absolute path **/home/bjoernp/.config/nvim**

Is this symlink necessary or would i be able to remove this link? How can i access my nvim folder?

```
~/.config$ cd nvim
-bash: cd: nvim: Too many levels of symbolic links
~/.config$ nvim
~/.config$ tree --noreport -fp
[drwxr-xr-x]  .
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  ./flutter
│   └── [-rw-r--r--]  ./flutter/tool_state
├── [lrwxrwxrwx]  ./nvim -> /home/bjoernp/.config/nvim
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  ./zathura
    └── [-rw-r--r--]  ./zathura/zathurarc
```

I am using an Ubuntu WSL

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the symbolic link pointing to itself by running the following command in your terminal:

```
unlink ~/.config/nvim
```

Comment: Now my whole nvim folder got deleted :/

Comment: You should consider using [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) for managing dotfiles

Comment: First, check if the nvim folder still exists in its original location (~/.config/nvim) by using the command:
ls ~/.config/nvim
    If the folder still exists, you can recreate the symbolic link by running:
ln -s /home/bjoernp/.config/nvim ~/.config/nvim
This command recreates the symbolic link pointing to the original nvim folder.

    If the nvim folder has been mistakenly deleted, you may need to restore it from a backup if available. Otherwise, you might need to recreate your Neovim configuration manually.